# jQuery - testing backend

Tags: php, jquery

I have backend .php file in which I decide what to return as the ajax response - how can I test this .php file? If I write a var_dump() of print() inside of this file - how can I check what does this echoes?

It's jquery ajax, and I don't see any ajax response in the firebug.

I'm using ajax to create remote validation rules inside of the jquery validation plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), jquery version is 1.9.0.

Comment: I usually test it without jQuery by going to the page directly with the browser.

Comment: yes this is a good idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything which is normally printed via PHP will be returned and shown in an ajax request, this includes `var_dump()`, `print_r()`, `print()` and `echo()`;

If you are not seeing a response, then there is probably an error in your PHP script, or the URL in your JQuery is looking somewhere else.

Comment: The trick is plugin's internals handle all ajax work for me, so I don't get any handle to display its response.

Comment: Open up firebug and use the console view to show live requests, the response for each request is shown in here.